# How to run "go mod download" from parent directory?

Tags: docker, go, go-modules

Project structure:

```
project_dir/
├── prj1/
│   ├── feature1/
│   ├─    |─ go.mod
│   ├─    |─ main.go
│   └─    |─ ...
│   └── ...
├── prj2/
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── main.go
│   └── Dockerfile
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

The code in prj2 is referencing a function from prj1/feature1 via the [go mod edit -replace](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/call-module-code) command. Now, this works fine locally but I need to deploy with Docker and I am facing issues.

My docker scripts look like this:

```
FROM golang:1.17.5 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.* ./
ADD ./prj1 ./prj1
RUN go mod download
...
```

Initially, I was running `docker build .` from inside prj2 without the `ADD` command in the docker file but `RUN go mod download` fails with:

> go mod download: github.com/name/project/prj1@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 (replaced by ../prj1/feature1/): reading /prj1/feature1/go.mod: open /prj1/feature1/go.mod: no such file or directory

So, I added the `ADD` command to the docker file to copy prj1. Next, I cd to project_dir and ran  `docker build -f ./prj2/Dockerfile` but `RUN go mod download` is now failing with

> go mod download: no modules specified (see 'go help mod download')

So basically, my question is, how do I tell the go command that the go.mod is inside  prj2?

Answer (score 2):

Considering your replace directive references ../prj1, your ADD should be

```
ADD ./prj1 ../prj1
```

And your should execute your docker from `prj2`, not `./prj2/Dockerfile`, or your `COPY go.* ./` would not copy any go file.

As commented, that would exclude prj1 from the context. So you must change your COPY to `COPY ./prj2/go.* ./`

Comment: If I run the docker build from inside prj2, then the ADD command wouldn't execute because prj1 is not in context. I got this error "failed to compute cache key: "/prj1" not found: not found".

Comment: @X09 So you would have to change the COPY command, then. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your docker build command is including the path to use as the build context?

```
docker build -f ./prj2/Dockerfile .  # <- period
```

If so, your build is running in the `project_dir/` folder. There's no `go.mod` file in `project_dir/`.

You should `cd` into the `prj2/` dir before trying to run `go mod download`

```
FROM golang:1.17.5 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.* ./
ADD ./prj1 ./prj1
RUN cd prj2/ && go mod download
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jesse. I got an error " /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to prj2".

Comment: @X09 Yes, that is why, in my answer, I suggest calling docker from the prj2 folder